# What is the best datastructure to use in Java for a "multidimensional" list?

Tags: java, list, data-structures

I need a dictionary-like data structure that stores information as follows:

```
key [value 1] [value 2] ...
```

I need to be able to look up a given value by supplying the key and the value I desire (the number of values is constant).  A hash table is the first thing that came to my mind but I don't think it can be used for multiple values.  Is there any way to do this with a single datastrucuture rather than splitting each key-value pair into a separate list (or hash table)? Also I'd rather not use a multi-dimensional array as the number of entries is not known in advance.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean about your list of values, and looking up a given value.  Is this basically a keyed list of name-value pairs?  Or do you want to specify the values by index?

If the latter, you could use a HashMap which contains ArrayLists - I'm assuming these values are String, and if the key was also a String, it would look something like this:

```
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> hkansDictionary = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

    public String getValue (String key, int valueIdx) {
        ArrayList<String> valueSet = hkansDictionary.get(key);
        return valueSet.get(valueIdx);
    }
```

If the former, you could use a HashMap which contains HashMaps.  That would look more like this:

```
    HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> hkansDictionary 
              = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();
    ----
    public String getValue (String key, String name) {
        HashMap<String, String> valueSet = hkansDictionary.get(key);
            return valueSet.get(name);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks..the HashMap of HashMaps is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a class that holds the two key values you want to look up, implement equals() and hashcode() to check/combine calls to the underlying values, and use this new class as the key to your Map.

Answer (score 0):

I would use

```
Map<Key,ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<Key,ArrayList<String>>
```

where you define Key as

```
public class Key{
    private String key;
    private String value;
    //getters,setters,constructor

    //implement equals and hashcode and tostring
}
```

then you can do

```
Key myKey = new Key("value","key");
map.get(myKey);
```

which would return a list of N items

Answer (score 0):

You can create a multidimensional array by first declaring it, then creating a method to ensure that new value keys are initialized before the put.  This example uses a Map with an embedded List, but you can have Maps of Maps, or whatever your heart desires.

*I.e., you must define your own **put** method that handles new value **initialization*** like so:

```
private static Map<String, List<USHCommandMap>> uSHCommandMaps = new HashMap<String, List<USHCommandMap>>();

public void putMemory() {

        if (!uSHCommandMaps.containsKey(getuAtom().getUAtomTypeName()))
            uSHCommandMaps.put(getuAtom().getUAtomTypeName(), new ArrayList<USHCommandMap>());

        uSHCommandMaps.get(getuAtom().getUAtomTypeName()).add(this);

    }
```